# XOR operation in C

Tags: c, char, xor

I've been facing a problem for a few hours with my XOR operation in C.

I'm trying to XOR the content of two `char *` between each other.

```
char* toto = malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
char* bob = malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
```

They both contain only `0` and `1` with 5 slots each.

The `printf` for `toto` returns `00011` and `bob` returns `11111`.

```
printf("%s", toto) => 11111
printf("%s", bob)  => 00011
```

These are the two values that I'm trying to XOR in the end.

First I proceed by steps :

1- Translate each of them into an `int` value

```
int val_toto = atoi(toto); 
int val_bob = atoi(bob);

// printf("%d", val_toto) => 11111
// printf("%d", val_bob)  => 11
```

As you can see the `0` in bob disapeared, no problem.

2- Use the XOR operator ^ between their respective same bits

```
int result = val_toto ^ val_bob;
```

And here comes the problem :

```
printf("%d", result) => 11116
```

The result of the XOR operation should be

```
  11111
^ 00011  // the 0 are taken care of even if not showed in printf
-------
  11100  // but I get 1116 ???
```

The real deal is that the problem occurs only when I use that combination for `toto` and `bob`. The XOR operations works fine for all of them, example :

```
toto => 00101   // as char*
bob => 000001
//then I use atoi() with each of them
toto => 101     // as int
bob => 1
```

And as a result I get what's expect :

```
101 XOR 1 => 100 //as int
```

Do you have any idea why it works fine in the combination above for instance but never when I have a `11111` ?

Thank you

Comment: `atoi` converts integers written in decimal, not binary. You have 11111 base 10 rather than 11111 base 2. The first is eleven thousand and change; the second is 31.

Comment: You are operating on decimal numbers as if they are binary ones, so that's not going to work well...

Comment: `char* toto = malloc(sizeof(char)*5);` -> `char* toto = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);`

Comment: Thank you for your answers I understood what I was doing wrong. I also had the malloc with size 5+1 in my code, just forgot to write it here, thanks for the reminder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was already pointed out in the comments and in [David Grayson answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67269561/6865932).

For a solution, unless you absolutely need to, you wouldn't need to convert to `int` at all, you can perform the `XOR` in each individual character and save the result in a new char array, something like this:

```
char toto[] = "11111";
char bobo[] = "00011";

size_t len = strlen(toto);  // use strlen only if toto is null terminated
                            // otherwise use the size of the array
char result[len]; 
                           
for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) // same here
{
    result[i] = (toto[i] ^ bobo[i]) + '0';
}

printf("%s", result); // again if the arrays are null terminated,
                      // otherwise print it in a for cycle
                      // using the array size
```

Output:

```
11100
```

If need be you can always safely convert the final value by using `strtol`:

```
char *end;
printf("%ld", strtol(result, &end, 2));
```

Output:

```
28
```

Pending error checks on `end` and `errno`.

[Live sample](https://godbolt.org/z/r3n33afb6)

Comment: Thank you for the sample, way cleaner than I did

Comment: @Wapitix, glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Both `atoi` and the `%d` specifier for printf assume you are dealing with decimal-formatted numbers, not binary.  When you did your XOR calculation, you assumed that 11111 and 00011 were binary.

Answer (score 1):

when you execute `int result = val_toto ^ val_bob;`, you are using the xor operator with two decimal, not binary numbers. 00011 becomes not 3 but rather 11 in decimal. to correct this mistake, try my code:

```
char *str="1100"; // in binary now convert it to decimal so it became 12 
char *endptr=NULL; // to detect any mistake 
int num = strtol(str, &endptr, 2); // strtol meams str to long 2 (binary base ) 
if (endptr!=NULL) { printf("error\n"); exit(1); }
printf("%d\n", num); // will print 12. now you can use it with xor
```